# In pygame can I purposely trigger an event?

Tags: python, pygame

I mean this as in in a section of a pygame project, this one to be exact:

```
for event in pygame.event.get:
```

Can the program append something to make it think, say, the caps lock key is currently being pressed down?

Comment: Please accept answers to show appreciations to the answerers if the answer solved your problem, it seems that you never accepted any answers in all 5 of your questions

Comment: Accepting doesn't only show appreciation, but also that your questions has been solved. So if your question has been answered then press the accept button to the left of the answer. If the answer doesn't answer your question, then leave a comment explaining why it didn't solve it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `pygame.event.post()` to "post" an event that can be retrieved with `pygame.event.get()`, usage: `pygame.event.post(Event)` ie:

```
import pygame
pygame.event.post(pygame.KEYDOWN)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
event = pygame.event.Event(pygame.KEYUP, key=pygame.K_r)<br>
pygame.event.post(event)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! On Stack Overflow, the **how** is important, but much of the site's quality level comes from people going out of their way to explain **why**. While a _code-only_ answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)